# How to cache http request in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented Caching HTTP request in Angular 5 application.However, my issue is that code which I have written will save data from First Http hit from api say '**API1**' at first and afterwards it will get data from stored variable i.e **countries**.But if I call this service again with different **API2** then it will fetch value from **countries**.

My Component Code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CacheService } from '../cache.service';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-caching',
 templateUrl: './caching.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./caching.component.css']
})
export class CachingComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private cacheService:CacheService){}
countries;
ngOnInit() {
  this.cacheService.get()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.countries = res;
  });
 }
}
```

My Service Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CacheService {
  countries;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  public get(): Observable<any> {
    if(this.countries != null) {
      console.log("Fetching Data From Cache!!!",this.countries);
      return Observable.of(this.countries);
    } 
    else {
      console.log("Fetching Data From Hit!!!"); 
      return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {})
        .map((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.countries = data;
        })
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();
    }
  }
}
```

I want that different API hit should be cached individually.

Comment: Create a wrapper around `HttpClient` and have it maintain a lookup based on the request parameters. If no previous call exists then call through to the real `HttpClient` and create an entry in the cache of the returned observable and return that observable.  If there was a previous call (ie. the observable was found in the cache) return the observable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually I am new to angular 5 so can you just guide me in how to implement your answer.Please.

Comment: I am sure if you google it you can find something or maybe someone else will post something but IMO this is too broad of a question with many possible answers.